# performing long loop

Tags: javascript, html

i want to perform a loop that writes strings in a `div` without overloading. I have got a list of names in an global `array` called `names`. The `array` is filled with about 2500 names. Now i want to write the names in a `div` using `ajax`. But when i want to loop the names, the script is kinda overloading and stops with an alert of the client. This is my loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
   document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += names[i] + "<br/>";
}
```

I also tried to interlace the loop in smaller steps like 100 (because i thought like that the loop wouldnt overload). I also tried it with `window.setTimeout("function(i)",0);` with the param i, that steps 100 each time the function gets called, until i am at the `length` of the array `names`.

I know there is an easy way. But i can't find that way..... would be pleased by getting help.

Thanks

Comment: There is a problem with your above code. The function document.getElementById is used to get an element with ID attribute, e.g, <div id="myElement"> </div>. I think you can try document.getElementByTagName('div').

Comment: @BlueSmith: there is no such method. There is `document.getElementsByTagName()` (note the plural), which returns a live `NodeList` of matching elements. I don't think this is what the OP needs.

Comment: Nice catch @AlexanderPavlov, my typos :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it this way:

```
    var content = '';

    for(var i = 0, n_length = names.length; i < n_length; i++) {
        content += names[i] + "<br/>";
    }

    document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += content;   // if the previous content should remain there
```

Please note that its faster, to store the abort value of a loop. Otherwise it would read the `length`-property of your `array` for each iteration of your loop (2500 x).

Also note that DOM-Manipulation is very verys slow, so its smart to reduce it to the lowest level possible. Better build your content separately and write it to the DOM once for all.

Comment: that was exactly what i need... of course you are right. you really saved me much time. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

You can code it like:

`document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = names.join('<br/>');`

This will set the inner html in single instruction, solving the load issue.

Comment: Exactly, your edit made it more clear. The names.join is of course not required, you could build up a string inside a loop as well, as long as you set the innerHTML in one go. Setting the innerHTML triggers the browsers rendering engine and what not, which is expensive.

Comment: @Jochem: this should not be an issue with "smart" browsers that delay the actual rendering to account for similar loops.

Comment: sry i just wrote div ... of course i meant the name of the div (div_name). i will try it with join... thanks for the answers

Comment: i didnt try it with join... building the content separately and write it to the DOM once for all worked out great